# Is there a callback that can be received when rxjava is finally shutting down Observable?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

In the function that creates the parent Observable, I want to do a certain task when all the child Observable is finished.

The operator closest to what I want in the official document is doFinally, but it actually shows different results than I think. Attach the test code below.

```
@Test
fun test() {
    val observer = TestObserver<Int>()
    createSingleWithDoFinally()
            .flatMapCompletable { createCompletable() }
            .doFinally {
                println("Actual Finally")
            }
            .subscribe(observer)

    observer.await()
}

private fun createSingleWithDoFinally(): Single<Int> {
    return Single.create<Int> { emitter ->
        emitter.onSuccess(1)
    }
            .doFinally {
                println("Expect doFinally")
            }
}

private fun createCompletable(): Completable {
    println("I Have Some Delay")
    return Completable.timer(2L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .andThen(Completable.defer {
                println("Delay One More Time")
                Completable.timer(3L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            })
}
```

Here is the output I want from the above code.

```
I Have Some Delay
Delay One More Time
Expect doFinally
Actual Finally
```

However, when I try to run the code, I get different results than expected.

```
I Have Some Delay
Expect doFinally
Delay One More Time
Actual Finally
```

Why are these results coming out? Also, do I have an operator that corresponds to what I want?

Comment: doFinally acts upon `onSuccess`, `onError` or `onComplete`. Since `flatMap` starts a delayed source upon `onSuccess` in your code, the finally gets executed on the Single but the rest of the sequence is still alive. The end of the sequence is where the final `subscribe` receives the signals above.